# Can't successfully Checkout using Braintree v.zero

Tags: commerce, payment-gateways

I'm integrating Braintree's v.zero drop-in ui as a payment method and on the checkout form.

I fill-up the credit card details and click "Continue to next step", the ajax submit and Braintree loads simultaneously. After a couple of seconds, Braintree finishes and returns the payment nonce. However, the form doesn't continue it's submission.

[image]
**How can I process Braintree first before the form so that I can get the payment nonce value?**

Module code

```
/**
 * Initializes the Braintree client library for use.
 *
 * @param $payment_method
 *   The payment method instance containing the Braintree credentials to use to
 *   submit API requests to Braintree.
 */
function commerce_braintree_vzero_initialize($payment_method) {
  require_once drupal_get_path('module', 'commerce_braintree_vzero') . '/braintree-php-2.37.0/lib/Braintree.php';

  Braintree_Configuration::merchantId($payment_method['settings']['merchant_id']);
  Braintree_Configuration::publicKey($payment_method['settings']['public_key']);
  Braintree_Configuration::privateKey($payment_method['settings']['private_key']);
  Braintree_Configuration::environment($payment_method['settings']['environment']);
}

/**
 * Implements hook_commerce_payment_method_info().
 */
function commerce_braintree_vzero_commerce_payment_method_info() {
  $payment_methods = array();

  $payment_methods['commerce_braintree_vzero'] = array(
    'title' => t('Braintree v.zero'),
    'description' => t('Payment method using Braintree v.zero.'),
    'active' => TRUE,
  );

  return $payment_methods;
}

/**
 * Returns the default settings for Braintree v.zero.
 */
function commerce_braintree_vzero_default_settings() {
  return array(
    'merchant_id' => '',
    'public_key' => '',
    'private_key' => '',
    'environment' => 'sandbox',
  );
}

/**
 * Payment method settings form.
 *
 * @param $settings
 *   Default settings provided from rules
 *
 * @return array
 *   Settings form array
 */
function commerce_braintree_vzero_settings_form($settings) {
  $form = array();

  // Merge default settings into the stored settings array.
  $settings = (array) $settings + commerce_braintree_vzero_default_settings();

  $form['merchant_id'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Merchant ID'),
    '#default_value' => $settings['merchant_id'],
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['public_key'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Public key'),
    '#default_value' => $settings['public_key'],
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['private_key'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Private key'),
    '#default_value' => $settings['private_key'],
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['environment'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => t('Braintree server'),
    '#options' => array(
      'sandbox' => ('Sandbox - use for testing, requires a Braintree Sandbox account'),
      'production' => ('Production - use for processing real transactions'),
    ),
    '#default_value' => $settings['environment'],
  );

  return $form;
}

/**
 * Payment method callback: checkout form.
 */
function commerce_braintree_vzero_submit_form($payment_method, $pane_values, $checkout_pane, $order) {
  // Load Braintree vzero php library
  commerce_braintree_vzero_initialize($payment_method);

  $clientToken = Braintree_ClientToken::generate();

  $form['test'] = array(
    '#markup' => '<div id="asd"></div>' .
    '<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script><input type="submit">',
  );

  $form['testt'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Test'),
  );

  drupal_add_js(array('vzero' => array('clientToken' => $clientToken)), 'setting');

  // Load vzero.js.
  $form['#attached']['js'] = array(
    drupal_get_path('module', 'commerce_braintree_vzero') . '/vzero.js',
  );

  return $form;
}

/**
 * Payment method callback: checkout form submission.
 */
function commerce_braintree_vzero_submit_form_submit($payment_method, $pane_form, $pane_values, $order, $charge) {
  commerce_braintree_vzero_transaction($payment_method, $order, $charge);
  drupal_set_message('success');
}

/**
 * Creates an example payment transaction for the specified charge amount.
 *
 * @param $payment_method
 *   The payment method instance object used to charge this payment.
 * @param $order
 *   The order object the payment applies to.
 * @param $charge
 *   An array indicating the amount and currency code to charge.
 */
function commerce_braintree_vzero_transaction($payment_method, $order, $charge) {
  $transaction = commerce_payment_transaction_new('commerce_braintree_vzero', $order->order_id);
  $transaction->instance_id = $payment_method['instance_id'];
  $transaction->amount = $charge['amount'];
  $transaction->currency_code = $charge['currency_code'];
  $transaction->status = COMMERCE_PAYMENT_STATUS_SUCCESS;

  $transaction->message = 'Test message';

  commerce_payment_transaction_save($transaction);
  return $transaction;
}
```

JS code

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.vzero = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

      if ($('#edit-commerce-payment-payment-method-commerce-braintree-vzerocommerce-payment-commerce-braintree-vzero', context).is(':checked')) {
        console.log("LOADED " + $('#asd').length);
        braintree.setup(settings.vzero.clientToken, "dropin", {
          container: "asd",
          paymentMethodNonceReceived: function (event, nonce) {
            console.log('nonce received ' + nonce);
            $('.form-item-commerce-payment-payment-details-testt input').val(nonce);

            $('body').delegate('#edit-continue', 'click', function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              console.log('prevent submit');
              return false;
            });
          }
        });
      }
      else {
        console.log("NOT CHECKED");
      }
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

**Note:** This here is the complete module if you would like to test. https://github.com/leolandotan/commerce_braintree_vzero

Answer (score 1):

this patch successfully adds support for Vzero https://www.drupal.org/node/2449881.